# C# Deserialize, then insert into SQLite database

Tags: c#, json, sqlite

I have the following JSON for model Project, which I cannot change:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "Project A"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "description": "Project B",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-13T09:30:51+02:00",
        "created_at": "2017-07-13T09:30:51+02:00"
    }
]
```

I have the following JSON for model Task, which I cannot change:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "project": {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "Project A"
        },
        "description": "Task 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "project": {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "Project A"
        },
        "description": "Task 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "project": {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "Project A"
        },
        "description": "Task 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "project": {
            "id": 6,
            "description": "Project B"
        },
        "description": "Task 4"
    }
]
```

I have the following 2 models:

```
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;

namespace BettyMultiModel.Resources.Model
{
    public class Models
    {

    }

    class Project : Models
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }

    class Task : Models
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }   

    }
}
```

I use this method to get the JSON into the SQLite database:

```
// Insert Records of type TType into database.
private async Task<string> InsertRecords<TType>(HttpResponseMessage response)
        where TType : Models
{
    try
    {
        DataBase db = new DataBase();

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TType>>(responseString);


        foreach (TType item in responseBody)
        {
            bool resultInsert = db.Insert(item);
        }

        return ResponseToMessage(response, "Insert Records");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Info("DeserializeObject", ex.Message);
        throw;
    }            

}
```

This works just fine when I only want to have the Id and Description properties of both models. But I would also like to store the relation between the Project model and the Task model / project id at the Task model.

When I parse the JSON with the tasks at http://json2csharp.com/, I get the following suggestion for the models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject // Which is Task
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Project project { get; set; }  // <-------- Extra property
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Using the models like this - with RootObject renamed to Task - results in a Exception: NotSupportedException: Don't know about BettyMultiModel.Resources.Model.Project

So I changed the classes to:

```
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;

namespace BettyMultiModel.Resources.Model
{
    public class Models
    {

    }

    class Project : Models
    {

        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }

    class Task : Models
    {

        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [OneToMany]
        public Project project { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The Exception is not thrown any longer, but when I have a look in the db file, there are still just the Id and Description columns and no reference to a relation between the 2 models.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT: Added method that creates the tables**

```
public void ClearTable<TType>()
        where TType : Models
{
    try
    {
        Log.Info("Folder DB: ", dbPath);

        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, dbPath))
        {
            connection.DropTable<TType>();
            connection.CreateTable<TType>();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Almost there...**

I also made a little mistake, a project has many tasks, so the attribute should be [ManyToOne]. The tables in the db look OK now. The project id is just not inserted in the ProjectId column, inside the Task model. Every row has value 0. I guess I need to figure out how to map the id of the nested project object to the ProjectId property of the class Task.

I've tried using the Newtonsoft.Json namespace like this, which inserts 1 row in the Task model and then starts throwing errors because of record the uniqueness of the id. JsonProperty("id") identifies it as the Id of Task, not of Project:

```
[JsonProperty("id"), ForeignKey(typeof(Project))]
public int ProjectId { get; set; }
```

These are the models now:

```
class Project : Models
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}

class Task : Models
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Project))]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: How is the database structure generated? I presume you call "CreateTable(type)" somewhere? If you do that, maybe you're missing a CreateTable(typeof(Project));

Comment: @TomTom: Indeed. I've added the method at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, in your question you're using the Twin Coders [SQLite-Net-Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) package I think there is an error in how you define your model.

If you look at the **Many to one** section in linked Bitbucket page you need to define a `ForeignKey` attribute in addition to the `ManyToOne` attribute. This is their example (notice the Bus and BusId properties on the Person class):

```
public class Bus
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Bus))]
    public int BusId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public Bus Bus { get; set; }
}
```

With your code, I believe all you have to do is use the following model:

```
class Project : Models
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    // The id of the task used in the relationship (this gets stored in the DB)
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Task))]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    // Meaning you have many projects to one task
    [ManyToOne]
    public Task Task { get; set; }
}

class Task : Models
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This comes very close to a solution. I made a small mistake with the ManyToOne, this had to be OneToMany. See an update a the the bottom of my post with the last issue, I hope. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Surely the attribute should be JsonProperty("projectId")?

Comment: Also, your updated model [ManyToOne] is representing that you have many tasks for each project. Is that desired? If you want many Projects for each task I would move the foreign key to Project like in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as simple as JsonProperty("projectId") or JsonProperty("ProjectId"). How would it make the reference of the JSON object "project"?

The '[ManyToOne]' attribute is correct. A Project can have one or more Task objects.

There are many examples online how to deserialize with Arrays inside an Object, but I can't find any with an Object inside an Oject / nested Objects.

Comment: I personally would use the [JsonIgnore] attribute on the ProjectId property, that way only the Id, Description & Project properties are serialised for the Task object.
Then I would use TypeNameHandling.All or TypeNameHandling.Auto as described on the Newtonsoft site: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: I still can't figure this out. I don't really understand how to apply this to my case. I'll leave it for now and take a step back to learn more of the C# basics. And some point I will be able to solve this. Thanks for your time TomTom!

Comment: No problem, if you ever come back to this issue may I recommend Entity Framework Core. I personally prefer it and is compatible with SQLite and SqlServer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/